# Does moto g6 (not moto G6 plus) Support google ARCore?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, google-developers-console

Does moto g6 (not moto G6 plus) Support google ARCore? Moto G5s plus supports it so Moto G6 should also do so?
But in the official page it only shows g6 plus g5splus and z2 force.

Does it support ARCore?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices

Comment: it shows that moto g5splus is supported but not g6? is it true

Comment: From what I know it is not the complete and up to date list, since devices like one plus 6 and mi 8 are arcore supported.

Comment: "The Measure app works on any device that supports ARCore, which is most recently launched phones. All of Google’s Pixels are supported, as well as the Galaxy S9, OnePlus 6, LG G7, and even cheaper phones like the **Moto G6**" from https://www.extremetech.com/mobile/272129-googles-measure-app-comes-to-all-arcore-phones So it is possible that moto g6 supports AR Core

Comment: has anyone with moto g6 tried it?

Comment: Don't know. If you have one, you can try to install from play store. If not available from playstore, you can try to sideload apk.

Comment: G6 is now officially supported. Check the provided link again